# saving a string as a csv file?

Tags: vb.net

in a winform how do i get one of those fancy windows "save file as" dialogues to appear so that the user can save a string as a file to a user-specified location on their hardrive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim myString = "Hello world!"  
Dim saveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2
saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
  If saveFileDialog.FileName <> "" Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, myString)
  End If
End If
```

There's not a whole lot to it.  Specify the file types to save as (in a fairly arcane format; review the docs for the Filter property to learn more), then show the dialog, and either a) retrieve the stream to write to (as shown here) with the `OpenFile` method, or retrieve the filename selected with the `FileName` property.

Review the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) for more.

Comment: but how do you specify the contents of the file?

Comment: oh ok, then i should rephrase my question. at runtime i am creating a string and i want to save this string as a file. how do i do this?

Comment: @alex: see my updated answer.  I'm not a VB person, but I think this will work for you.

Comment: thank you but i am getting Error 2 Name 'File' is not declared

Comment: ah, my bad.  you need to import the system.io namespace, or just grab my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from my project.  I start the SFD in the user's my documents folder because they have guaranteed write access there.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = suggestedName + ".csv";
sfd.Title = "Choose Location For CSV";
sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
  return;
}
string outputFileName = sfd.FileName;
```

Comment: crap I didn't see the vb.net tag sorry my version is c#

Answer (score 0):

> oh ok, then i should rephrase my question. at runtime i am creating a string and i want to save this string as a file. how do i do this?

```
Dim theStringToSave as String = "some string here"
Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()

sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|(*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*"
sfd.FilterIndex = 2
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, theStringToSave)
End If
```

Comment: i am getting A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score -1):

Search for the SaveFileDialog.